# Specifically match multiple words in string with .htaccess/RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

(I did the best I could with my post title, but it may not really explain my question properly.)

For the sake of simplicity, say the 3 user agent strings that I want to target are:

```
Blue V1.0 | Red V1.0 Lite | Green V1.0
```

I can do this with this rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blue|red|green" [NC]
```

But I only want to match the 'Red' user agent if it **also** contains the word "Lite" at some point later on in the string. If the user agent includes "Red", but not "Lite", I want to ignore it.

I was hoping that I could use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blue|red+lite|green" [NC]
```

Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blue|red.*lite|green" [NC]
```

will match `red` only if it is **followed** by `lite`.